# nodejs немного кривой

Tags: javascript, node.js

Почему при установке node.js 7.0.0 показывает что установлена v0.10.24?
http://puu.sh/s9Atl.png

Answer (score 2):

1. Убедиться в одинаковости битности, если работаешь на x64.
2. Проверить переменную path.
3. Проверить отсутствие node в текущем каталоге.

Comment: 1) Одинакова
2) Путь правильный
3) Отсутствует
Если запускать из пуска Node.js command prompt ,то всё нормально показывает, но это неудобно.

Comment: @xDololow 2) По всей видимости, нет.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь пути , в консоли *echo %PATH%* или *set* , видимо в переменных PATH есть путь к более старой версии ноды и он прописан раньше новой, поэтому и выводит более старую